# How to send text which invoves hyperlink and plain text via intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, hyperlink, plaintext

I'd like to know how to send hyper link and plain text together concatenated (for example share button in the application details page in play store). I have this situation, I am designing a share button in my android application, which on clicking should take the user to any texting application ( this I have done this `Intent.createChooser()` ). My problem is I either get a plain text on using `Intent.setType(text/plain)` or just a hyperlink using `Intent.setType(text/html)` in which case I get only few applications to choose from (Gmail,Drive etc..). Below is my code:

```
            Intent sharing_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            sharing_intent.setType("text/*");
            sharing_intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Profile Changer");
            String app_link ="market://details?id=" + getPackageName();
            String hyperlink="<a href=\""+ app_link +"\">"+app_link+"</a>";
            String share_app_text= Html.fromHtml(hyperlink) + "\nHey! Download this application.";
            sharing_intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,share_app_text);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharing_intent,"Recommend via"));
```

Could someone please tell me how to resolve this and it done? Thanks in advance